# Python: Concatenate similiar objects in List

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a list containing strings as `['Country-Points']`.
For example:

```
lst = ['Albania-10', 'Albania-5', 'Andorra-0', 'Andorra-4', 'Andorra-8', ...other countries...]
```

I want to calculate the average for each country without creating a new list. So the output would be (in the case above):

```
lst = ['Albania-7.5', 'Andorra-4.25', ...other countries...]
```

Would realy appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

EDIT:
this is what I've got so far. So, "data" is actually a dictionary, where the keys are countries and the values are list of other countries points' to this country (the one as Key). Again, I'm new at Python so I don't realy know all the built-in functions.

```
for key in self.data:
        lst = []
        index = 0
        score = 0
        cnt = 0
        s = str(self.data[key][0]).split("-")[0]
        for i in range(len(self.data[key])):
            if s in self.data[key][i]:
                a = str(self.data[key][i]).split("-")
                score += int(float(a[1]))
                cnt+=1
                index+=1
                if i+1 != len(self.data[key]) and not s in self.data[key][i+1]:
                    lst.append(s + "-" + str(float(score/cnt)))
                    s = str(self.data[key][index]).split("-")[0]
                    score = 0
        self.data[key] = lst
```

Comment: How about you show us the way you did it that required a new list, and we'll tell you how to alter that code so you don't have to create a new list.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a new list?

Comment: Often an asker put some constraints that even himself don't know why.

Comment: Doing this in-place (at least in the sense of never reallocating or creating temp lists, which is typically what 'in place' means) is going to be impossible (or at least horrifically inefficient, you could do it bubble-sort style I suppose), as you can't do numeric operations on a string, and unless you know exactly how many of each value there are and their exact locations, you're going to need to keep some kind of running list of averages for each name anyway. As @jme says, why do you want to avoid creating a new list?

Comment: Essentially, it seems you're falling into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probabkly do this with an intermediate dictionary.

```
def country(s):
  return s.split('-')[0]

def value(s):
  return float(s.split('-')[1])

def country_average(lst):
  country_map = {}|
  for point in lst:
    c = country(pair)
    v = value(pair)
    old = country_map.get(c, (0, 0))
    country_map[c] = (old[0]+v, old[1]+1)
  return ['%s-%f' % (country, sum/count) 
          for (country, (sum, count)) in country_map.items()]
```

It tries hard to only traverse the original list only once, at the expense of quite a few tuple allocations.

Answer (score 4):

`itertools.groupby` with a suitable key function can help:

```
import itertools

def get_country_name(item):
    return item.split('-', 1)[0]

def get_country_value(item):
    return float(item.split('-', 1)[1])

def country_avg_grouper(lst) : 
    for ctry, group in itertools.groupby(lst, key=get_country_name):
        values = list(get_country_value(c) for c in group)
        avg = sum(values)/len(values)
        yield '{country}-{avg}'.format(country=ctry, avg=avg)

lst[:] = country_avg_grouper(lst)
```

The key here is that I wrote a function to do the change *out of place* and then I can easily make the substitution happen *in place* by using slice assignment.

Comment: This certainly accomplishes the goal if the point of the 'in place' is only to ensure that other places that have aliased `lst` will all still reference the same list, rather than a true 'in place' list operation. Which I certainly hope is the point.

Comment: @aruisdante -- I think that's generally what is meant by 'in place' in python.  The implementation can make whatever temporary data structures that it wants to do any operation you can cook up. . .